# Oracle Data Access issue from VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, registry

I was building application in Visual studio 2010. I used Oracle Data Access . dll version 2.112.1.0 . Everything was working fine till i reinstalled Toad for oracle 12.2 and oracle client 11g 64 bit version. Due to which now i run the application and as soon as Oracle command is run it gives me "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" if i set Enable application to 32 bit True in IIS. OR Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client if i set Enable Application to 32 bit as false.

Also in the registry i have  ODP.NET version 2.112.1.0 REGISTERED WITH RIGHT dll path C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN

So do i need to reinstall the oracle client for using Oracle data access dll version 2.112.1.0

Comment: I've always ran into Oracle problems when installing multiple instances on one machine. I wish oracle was better in handling this. If it's complaining about `provider not compatible` when you try the 32-bit version of `Oracle.DataAccess` I would try to see if it works with the 64-bit version of `Oracle.DataAccess` since you installed the oracle client 64-bit version. You can find both versions somewhere in the `ODP.NET` folder inside of the main `Oracle` folder installed when you re-installed Toad.

Comment: Got a simular problem, the solution was to give read write access to the oracle folder.

Comment: i have tried with oracle data access .dll v 2.112.1.0 from GAC64 and pointed to it. But still same issue. But i see my VS 2010 is 32 BIT application.  So is that i need to install client with 32 bit for compatibility with oracle data access .dll v 2.112.1.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

For .Net applications we faced the same issue and went with the Managed Provider from Oracle. The version we used was Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver 12.1.0.1.0 but you should find the same for what you are looking at the link below.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

1) Go ahead and download the ODP.NET, Managed Driver (xcopy version) and unzip. 
2) Browse to the odp.net\managed\common and select Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll as reference in VS2010

Hope the above steps should work in VS for you.

During deployment on the server make sure they run the following from the zip folder so that the configuration is done appropriately

For 32-bit .NET Framework: .\odp.net\managed\x86 
For 64-bit .NET Framework: .\odp.net\managed\x64

Comment: I still get the error. I have oracle.dll version 2.112.1.0 and oracle client installed as well. Also i have odp.net in registry. 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception. ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client